# At Dublin airport, is preclearance available for flights to Canada, or just to the USA?

Tags: usa, customs-and-immigration, canada, dublin, pre-clearance

As an EU citizen I have a Canadian ETA. I am travelling to Canada from Dublin airport. There is US preclearance; is it also for travel to Canada or only for the US?

Comment: Editing to be clear - the issue isn't whether you are a "Canadian traveller" or not but where you are travelling to.

Comment: @KateGregory, you have edited it to Canadian flights, are you sure OP does not fly to Canada via the USA?

Comment: i guess the op can edit if that is the case

Comment: Of course, even if the OP goes through US preclearance in Ireland, they will still have to pass through Canada customs at their point of entry to Canada.

Answer (score 12):

Preclearance is for flights to the US, for all passengers on those flights.

It is not guaranteed to be available for all flights to the US, but it seems to be for most.

There is no preclearance for any other country as far as I know; I have never heard of preclearance for flights to Canada.

Comment: Correct, I flew Dublin to YYZ this year. No preclearance, dealt with customs in YYZ on arrival just as any other international flight to Canada.